# Customizing Windows 10 Start Menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

Windows 10 default Start Menu looks like this:

[image: Start Menu]

Without using third party application Classic Shell, please let me know, how to change it in Windows 7 Style Menu?

Regards

InTech

Comment: You can't; What you want to do, requires, a program like classic shell.  There are many alternatives so you might try one of those

Comment: see my anser in the dup topic. Use StartIsBackk++, it also brings Win7 taskbar style back.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use Classic Shell, you can try Start Menu 8.  I don't think there's any way to modify the start menu in Windows 10 without using some kind of software.

http://download.cnet.com/Start-Menu-8/3000-2072_4-75852660.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prEe_W7eKkk.

The first link is to download Start Menu 8, and the second link is a YouTube tutorial if you need it.

Comment: Your suggested version of the program doesn't support the current version of Windows 10.  The official website for the program hasn't received an update in over a year.  I would be shocked if it even works with 1511 let alone 1607 or 1703.  The use of this program will result in your inability to use your pc more then likely

Comment: Funny.  I have 1607 and it works just fine.